# Create model from server

Tags: backbone.js, asynchronous

I found an example of how update  the model . An example is shown below :

```
   var Sidebar = Backbone.Model.extend({
      param:'sasha',
      time:(new Date()).getTime()
    });

    window.sidebar = new Sidebar;
    sidebar.set("name","sasha");
    sidebar.set("time",(new Date()).getTime())
    Backbone.sync("update",sidebar,{
      url:'1.php',
      success:function(data){
        debugger
        console.log('success');
        sidebar.set('rand',data.b)
      },
      error:function(){
        console.log('error')
      }
    })
```

**1.php**

```
$time =  rand();
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => $time);

echo json_encode($arr);
```

I could not find an example of a query "create" .
Help create a generation of a new model from the server?

I read that one with attributes describing this process is a property "id"  ... I wanted to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not really using Backbone as designed :P

The first thing to realize is that when you do `Model.extend` you are creating a `constructor`/prototype/blueprint for a Model, NOT an actual `instance` new model.

It contains methods and properties that are meta to ALL instances of the model. An example of a "meta" property would be:

- `url`: the url you will be hitting to perform actions on it.
- `parse`: a function to "unwrap" the response (ex: if it has an outer "data" wrapper)

None of these properties are actual attributes of the model. They are just meta to performing actions on them.

Once you have a Constructor you can create new models off of it by using `new`.

```
var Sidebar = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url:'1.php'
});

var sidebar = new Sidebar({
    param:'sasha',
    time:(new Date()).getTime()
});
```

The difference between an `update` and a `create` for Backbone is the presence of an ID element (primary key). This is how you would identify it in a database. You would use `.save()` to both create the model and update it

```
//Will create the model on the server by doing a `POST` to the `url`
sidebar.save();
```

Which will effectively do:

```
POST 1.php
{
   "param": "Sasha",
   "date": 12312311228
}
```

Server responds with a copy of the model and an ID to identify it (the ID from the DB)

```
{
   "id": 123,
   "param": "Sasha",
   "date": 12312311228
}
```

Backbone will take the ID and save it to the model. From that point on `save` will to `UPDATE` instead of `POST`.

So:

```
model.save({new:'attribute'});

UPDATE 1.php
{
   "id": 123,
   "new": "attribute",
   "param": "Sasha",
   "date": 12312311228
}
```